# An analytical number theory problem

Tags: number-theory

I was given this problem:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Compute the sum of the numbers of the form $\dfrac1{a_1\cdots a_k}$ whose denominators are the product of all elements of each non empty subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$

1. The trivial solution would be $$-1+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}}\dfrac1{\prod A}$$
2. The least trivial answer I can give is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{s_n(k)}k$$ where $s_n(k)$ is the number of ways to write $k$ as a product of a increasing sequence of integer numbers from $1$ to $n$.

None of these answers seems to meet to the word 'compute'. Any ideas? Particularly, I'd like to know if there is a nice result for $s_n$.

Comment: Have you tried computing it for $n=2,3,4?$  That is often a good way to find inspiration.  Your version 2 is a good place to start.

Comment: expand $\prod_{n=1}^k (1+\frac1{a_n})$

Comment: Your "trivial solution" is a step in the right direction.  Specifically, the sum $$\sum_{A \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}} \frac1{\prod A}$$ is primed for an induction with respect to $n$, as any such $A$ is either of the form $A=B$ or $A=B\cup \{n\}$ for some $B \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n-1\}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm rather shocked at what that turns up. That's hilarious. Now I want to figure out proof myself.

Comment: For $n=2$ the sum is $1+1/2+1/2=2$. For $n=3$, the sum is $1+1/2+1/3+1/2+1/3+1/6+1/6=3$

Answer (score 2):

We get from first principles using a generating function

$$\sum_{k=1}^n [z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n \left(1+\frac{z}{q}\right)
\\ = -1 + \sum_{k=0}^n [z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n \left(1+\frac{z}{q}\right)
= -1 + \prod_{q=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)
\\ = -1 + \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{q+1}{q}
= -1 + \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The comment I posted suggests that $S_n=n$. Since $S_1=1$ and
$$S_{n+1}=-1+(S_n+1)\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)=S_n+\frac{S_n+1}{n+1}$$
the 'suggestion' seems to be true.